# Counting multiples of three and filling empty slots with alternate content

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I am displaying a listing of TV shows on a website in rows with three columns per row. When I do not have enough shows in multiples of three, I want to fill the empty slots with alternate content.

The code I am using to display the listing is:

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($show_listingsRecords as $record): ?>
    <?php if($counter % 3 == 0) : ?>
        <!-- ROW 3 -->
        <div> ... display name + description + link ...</div>
    <?php elseif ($counter % 3 == 2) : ?>
        <!-- ROW 2 -->  
        <div> ... display name + description + link ...</div>
    <?php elseif  ($counter % 3 == 1): ?>
        <!-- ROW 1 -->  
        <div> ... display name + description + link ...</div>
    <?php endif; ?>       
    <?php $counter++; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I've tried to insert the following conditional statement, but it does not work because the `foreach()` loop dictates the number of records to be displayed. How do I achieve displaying alternate content if slots 2 or 2 & 3 are empty?

```
<?php if(!$show_listingsRecords): ?>
    Display my alternate content
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: You need to put more details, to understand, what you are looking to achieve. Putting a image will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing all of the processing first and then only using `foreach()` to display it.

The first step is checking what kind of modification is needed to prepare your `$show_listingsRecords` array.

- If there are no subarrays, then you will need to use all three `$alternates` subarrays.
- If the number of subarrays does not evenly divide by `$chunk_size` (number of subarrays per batch), then merge only the necessary amount of subarrays from `$alternates` to complete the "batch".

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be2a2b0a6e65977ffbbdfa568e19cdb3f2f408da))

```
$show_listingsRecords=array(
    array("name"=>1,"description"=>2,"link"=>3),
    array("name"=>4,"description"=>5,"link"=>6),
    array("name"=>7,"description"=>8,"link"=>9),
    array("name"=>10,"description"=>11,"link"=>12),
    array("name"=>13,"description"=>14,"link"=>15)
);

$alternates=array(
    array("name"=>"backup1A","description"=>"backup1B","link"=>"backup1C"),
    array("name"=>"backup2A","description"=>"backup2B","link"=>"backup2C"),
    array("name"=>"backup3A","description"=>"backup3B","link"=>"backup3C")  // needed if no listings at all
);

$chunk_size=3;  // 3 is used in this case

// conditionally prepare array
if(!$size=sizeof($show_listingsRecords)){  // if no listings at all (empty array)
    $show_listingsRecords=$alternates;
}elseif($over=$size%$chunk_size){  // $over is how many extra elements beyond "even" (0,1,2 in this case)
    $show_listingsRecords=array_merge($show_listingsRecords,array_slice($alternates,0,$chunk_size-$over));
}

// display
foreach(array_chunk($show_listingsRecords,$chunk_size) as $batch){  // iterate in batches
    echo "<div>\n";
        foreach($batch as $listing){  // iterate the arrays in the batch
            echo "\t<div>",implode(' + ',$listing),"</div>\n";
        }
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <div>1 + 2 + 3</div>
    <div>4 + 5 + 6</div>
    <div>7 + 8 + 9</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>10 + 11 + 12</div>
    <div>13 + 14 + 15</div>
    <div>backup1A + backup1B + backup1C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add another loop after your code:

```
//As long as there is some remainder
while($counter % 3) {
    //add desired content
    switch($counter++ % 3) {
        case 1: break;
        case 2: break;
    }
}
```

A would also suggest you use a constant/variable instead of magic number 3. If you decide to use 4 columns in the future all you need to do is change the variable and add conditions for the fourth column instead of manually checking and rewriting the "correct" numbers 3 (find and replace could change number 3 in other part of your code you do not want to change).